# How can I get the GET, PUT, DELETE API view in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm learning django Rest Framework and I'm trying to get the GET, DELETE, PUT APi view but it does not work.

I use functions.

1. Here is my view_list where It looks like working:

[image]

My code views.py::

```
  @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
  @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly])
  def city_list(request, format=None):
 """
List all cities, or create a new city.
"""
 if request.method == 'GET':
     cities = City.objects.all()
     serializer = CitySerializer(cities, many=True)
     #return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
     return Response(serializer.data)

 elif request.method == 'POST':
    #data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = CitySerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=request.user)
        #return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    #return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

2. Here is my view_detail function where I want to get GET, PUT, DELETE API VIEW but It does not work!

[image]

Here is my code in views.py:

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly])
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def city_detail(request, pk, format=None):
 """
Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
"""
try:
    city = City.objects.get(pk=pk)
except City.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == 'GET':
    serializer = CitySerializer(city)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'PUT':
    #data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = CitySerializer(city, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    city.delete()
    return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here is my permissions.py:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
"""

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
    # So we'll alaways allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True
    
    #Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

here is my app.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from api import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [

path('users/', views.UserList.as_view()),
path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),

path('cities/', views.city_list),
path('cities/create/', views.city_create),
path('cities/<int:pk>/', views.city_detail),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

So, do you have an idea of why it does not work?

Comment: How are you validating if this is not working?

Comment: I can validate it but If I go to myview/detail the put, delete, get api view does not appear. You can see it on the pictures that for my view_list get and post methods are displayed but not when i go to myview/detail/